# I want a php algorithm for the following issue

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array like -

```
array(
    "C"  => array('A','A1','A2','B',B1'),
    "C1" => array('A','A1','A2','B',B1'),
    "A"  => array('B','B1','C',C1'),
    "B1" => array('A','A1','A2','C',C1'),
    "B1" => array('A','A1','A2','C',C1'),
    "A2" => array('B','B1','C',C1'),
    "A1" => array('B','B1','C',C1')
);
```

I want a script which will assign a value out of the given array for each key,

Result will be like -

```
C   A/A1/A2/B/B1    -   A  //I can assign any value from A/A1/A2/B/B1
C1  A/A1/A2/B/B1    -   A1 //Once A is assigned for the above key then C1 will get value from A1/A2/B/B1 skipping the 'A' which is assigned to key 'C'
A   B/B1/C/C1       -   B  //Now A will get value from B/B1/C/C1
B1  A/A1/A2/C/C1    -   A2 //B1 will get value from A2/C/C1
B   A/A1/A2/C/C1    -   C  //Likewise all the values will be assigned uniquely
A2  B/B1/C/C1       -   B1
A1  B/B1/C/C1       -   C1
```

The condition is that an the same value will not be assigned to multiple keys i.e all the keys will have different value. (Check the above result to know what exactly needs to be assigned)

Comment: And where are you stuck? Looks pretty straight forward to me. Use a lookup for the "taken" values and assign the first, which is not in there ...

Comment: I did the same but the issue occurs in some cases as A1 can only get value from B/B1/C/C1 but if they are already assigned to above keys then it returns an error, so i need some script to equally assign all the values to the keys uniquely. ( Actually there are 7 keys - 7 values so i need to assign them uniquely )

Comment: Then have a look at bipartite matching algorithms. If there are enough values for bot parts, this can give you the maximum possible matching.

Comment: @CbxDev i update my solution, check it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = array(
    "C"  => array('A','A1','A2','B','B1'),
    "C1" => array('A','A1','A2','B','B1'),
    "A"  => array('B','B1','C','C1'),
    "B1" => array('A','A1','A2','C','C1'),
    "B" => array('A','A1','A2','C','C1'),
    "A2" => array('B','B1','C','C1'),
    "A1" => array('B','B1','C','C1')
);

$assigned = array();
$result = array();
foreach($data as $k => $v) {
   for($i=0;$i<count($v);$i++) {
     if (!in_array($v[$i],$assigned)) {
        $assigned[] = $v[$i];
        $result[$k] = $v[$i];
        break;
     }
   }
}
var_dump($result);
```

output:

```
array(7) {
  ["C"]=>
  string(1) "A"
  ["C1"]=>
  string(2) "A1"
  ["A"]=>
  string(1) "B"
  ["B1"]=>
  string(2) "A2"
  ["B"]=>
  string(1) "C"
  ["A2"]=>
  string(2) "B1"
  ["A1"]=>
  string(2) "C1"
}
```

this solution is not good enaugh ;) if you define C1 as array('A') then C1 will be without value, to prevent that you can try to check is there posibility to assign values in different configuration.

```
$data = array(
    "C"  => array('A','A1'),
    "C1" => array('A'),
    "A"  => array('B','B1','C','C1'),
    "B1" => array('A','A1','A2','C','C1'),
    "B" => array('A','A1','A2','C','C1'),
    "A2" => array('B'),
    "A1" => array('B','B1','C','C1')
);

$assigned = array();
$keys = array_keys($data);
for($i=0;$i<count($keys);$i++) {
    getValue($data, $assigned, $keys, $i);  
}
function getValue($data, &$assigned, $keys, &$i, $x = null) {
   $j = $x === null ? 0 : array_search($x, $data[$keys[$i]]) +1;
   for($j; $j<count($data[$keys[$i]]); $j++) {
      $v = $data[$keys[$i]][$j];
      if(!in_array($v, $assigned)) {
         $assigned[$keys[$i]] = $v;
         return;
      }
   }
   $i--;
   if ($i < 0) {
       throw new Exception('no solutions');
   }
   $val = $assigned[$keys[$i]];
   $assigned[$keys[$i]] = null; 
   getValue($data, $assigned, $keys, $i, $val);
}
var_dump($assigned);
```

Comment: Can you please check for this array -> `array(
 "A" => array('B',B1','C',C1'),
 "B" => array('A','A1','A2','C',C1'),
 "C" => array('A','A1','A2','B',B1'),
 "B1" => array('A','A1','A2','C',C1'),
 "A1" => array('B','B1','C',C1'),
 "C1" => array('A','A1','A2','B',B1'),
 "A2" => array('B','B1','C',C1')
);` Thanks.

Comment: `array(7) {
  ["A"]=>
  string(1) "B"
  ["B"]=>
  string(1) "A"
  ["C"]=>
  string(2) "A1"
  ["B1"]=>
  string(2) "A2"
  ["A1"]=>
  string(1) "C"
  ["C1"]=>
  string(2) "B1"
  ["A2"]=>
  string(2) "C1"
}`

Comment: Hi @szapio, thanks for your help i really appreciate it, but i have an issue that when the array is huge it takes alot of time to give the result, can you please help me and optimize it for large data ? Thanks.

Comment: @Cbx Dev. i expected this for large arrays, this solution just trying to fetch all values, but it's doing it in a simplest way => check if can assign value if not back to previous step and assign another value, not very optimised but workinkg. I have to think a little how to improve that, for now i can only suggest you to order this array  of arrays ascending by array length. If first arrays will be shorter then algorithm will faster find solution. That's a tough problem, maybe there is an algorithm to do it faster, you have to search :) If i got idea i will write :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, ill try to work on my array :)

Comment: @Cbx Dev, one more thing, maybe it improves a little but I don't know because those are additional operations , at start you can merge all those arrays and check if merged array length < array length of base array, if it's shorter, then there is not solution, because there is more elements than values that you can assign.

Comment: @CbxDev oh and one more thing :D post this algortihm as a new question, how to improve it, maybe someone on stack will find solution :)

Comment: Ya sure :) Thanks for your help btw :D @szapio